# Can't see my UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm writing an app with a UICollectionViewController.

I've created the layout in with a storyboard. Subclassed UICollectionViewController and linked the two in IB. I've also given it a Storyboard ID of "ImageCollectionViewController".

I've also subclassed a UICollectionViewCell and linked it with my prototype cell in IB as well as given it the Identifier "ImageCell".

This is my constructor I call to create my custom UICollectionViewController:

```
-(id)initWithGroup:(CatalogGroup*)group
{
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle: nil];
    self = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImageCollectionViewController"];
    if (self) {

        [self setGroup:group];

        // Register the type of cell for collection view
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[ImageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImageCell"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Now this all seems to work. All the delegate methods are being called in the collectionViewController. For example:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

My cells are being initialized and passed back with:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* identifier = @"ImageCell";
    ImageCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ImageItem* item = [[self fetchedResultsController].fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(cell) {
        // Set up label
        cell.label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        cell.label.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.label setText:item.labelText];

        NSData* imageData = item.imageData;
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [cell setImageView:imageView];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Yet when I push the view controller onto the stack. None of the cells are there?
Is there anything wrong with my stack?

The background color I set for the CollectionView in IB is showing so I believe it's being created properly. The cells are initialized. The delegate methods are being called so I don't know where to start debugging.

Comment: Can we see `numberOfItemsInSection:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your custom cell looks like, but generally, it should be a subview of cell.contentView:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:myContentView];
```

So, instead of [cell setImageView:imageView], you might try

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this exactly.

Comment: Even if the imageView is set up in IB as a subview to the cell?

Comment: I'd also like clarification on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your collection view by setting the **background color of the cell** in collection view cell custom class. This will ensure your cells are configured properly. Now come to your problem(It is only a guess since you are not shown your cell class). If you are setting image view of the cell in nib, you should _*registerNib* instead of _*registerClass*_for the cell. Other wise you should add the image view as the sub view to the cell.contentView